# How can I filter a DataSource before applying it to a ListView

Tags: c#, linq, listview

I have an Entity datasource, which I need to filter before passing it to the ListView. Here is the unfiltered version (works great):

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
ListView1.DataSource = db.Cars;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

I'm trying to understand how to select only the Cars that are blue (a field/property/row in the database), and pass just those Cars to the ListView. I've been trying variations on this:

```
String selectedColor = "blue";
DataContext db = new DataContext();
ListView1.DataSource = db.Cars.Any(m => m.Cars.color == selectedColor);
ListView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this be more like,

```
ListView1.DataSource = db.Cars.Where(car => car.Color == selectedColor);
```

Your `db.Cars.Any(m => m.Cars.color == selectedColor)` [Correction: should be m.Color instead of m.Cars.Color if you wanted to use it by the way] statement will return true if in your Cars collection there's at least one car with color value as that of the selectedColor.

Answer (score 1):

`Any()` Returns a bool. You need `Where()`

Answer (score 1):

I would also wrap your context using a `using` statement. This should take care of your context's disposal automatically.

```
String selectedColor = "blue";
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   ListView1.DataSource = db.Cars.Where(m => m.Cars.color == selectedColor);
   ListView1.DataBind();
}
```