# ObjectDataSource not filtering the Telerik RadListView

Tags: c#, wcf, telerik, radlistview

A Textbox (RadTextBox) is supposed to filter a ListView (RadListView) through the use of an ObjectDataSource's FilterExpression. The underlying datasource of the ObjectDataSource is a WCF Service.

It is not working. In all of my trial and error, all I can get was the entire dataset to bind to the ListView or no records at all. I was not able to get a select few records by filtering it from input in the Textbox.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoCv8AbKfso) is a helper video (a bit desperate at this point...)

Thanks in advance!

RadListView:

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" runat="server"
                                    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowPaging="True"
                                    ItemPlaceholderID="ListingsContainer" Width="940px" SkinID="Bootstrap">
```

ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" EnablePaging="true" TypeName="manageListingsController" SelectMethod="GetProducts" StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
                    SelectCountMethod="GetProductsCount" FilterExpression="ItemID = '{0}%'" InsertMethod="InsertProduct" DeleteMethod="DeleteProduct" UpdateMethod="UpdateProduct" OldValuesParameterFormatString="Original_{0}" SortParameterName="sortExpression">
                    <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="@ItemID" ControlID="txtItemID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ItemID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SiteID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Condition" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ToAP" Type="Boolean" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ItemID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SiteID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Condition" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ToAP" Type="Boolean" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ItemID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SiteID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

GetProducts Method:

```
public DataTable GetProducts(int startRowIndex,
    int maximumRows,
    string sortExpression)
{
    ProductsAPI.ProductsClient pCl = new ProductsAPI.ProductsClient();
    DataTable n = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        rowCount = temp.Count;
        try
        {
            n = Help.ToDataTable(temp.ProductData.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(null, ex);
    }

    return n;
}
```

WCF GetProducts OperationContract:

```
        [OperationContract]
    public ResultData GetProducts(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string filterExpression)
    {
        DAL.Products.Products p = DAL.Products.Products.Instance();

        return p.GetDataAndCount(startRowIndex, maximumRows, sortExpression, filterExpression);
    }
```

WCF GetDataAndCount Method:

```
public ResultData GetDataAndCount(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string filterExpression)
    {
        //http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/declarative/defaultcs.aspx
        //http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/client/webservicedatabinding/defaultcs.aspx

        GridLinqBindingData<v_mp_GenListings_Data> data = RadGrid.GetBindingData(
            (new Entities()).v_mp_GenListings_Data.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID),
            startRowIndex, maximumRows, sortExpression, filterExpression);

        ResultData result = new ResultData();

        result.ProductData = data.Data.OfType<v_mp_GenListings_Data>().Select(p => new Product()
        {
            ItemID = p.ItemID,
            SKU = p.SKU,
            ID = p.ID,
            SiteID = p.SiteID,
            MarketPlaceType = p.MarketplaceType,
            SiteName = p.SiteName,
            //AccOverride = p.AccOverride,
            //ToAP = p.ToAP,
            //CeilingPriceFixed = p.CeilingPriceFixed,
            //Min = p.Min,
            NightModeID = p.NightModeID,
            NightModeCode = p.NightModeCode,
            ToMAP = p.ToMAP,
            ConditionID = p.ConditionID,
            MerchantID = p.MerchantID,
            ProductID = p.ProductID,
            Quantity = p.Quantity,
            Price = p.Price,
            URL = p.URL

        }).ToList();

        result.Count = data.Count;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Not too familiar with the ASP based way of filtering, but if this is really a big issue, why not trying filtering based on the more manual approach, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837870/how-can-i-filter-a-datasource-before-applying-it-to-a-listview

Comment: The GetProducts Method (look above) must have this signature:

(int startRowIndex,
    int maximumRows,
    string sortExpression)

Otherwise the control doesn't know how to use it.

So how will you get the textbox string[] in the GetProducts scope?

Comment: try to add select parameter instead of filter parameter

Comment: Thanks Feras. The select parameter helped in modifying the default signature search through all methods.

Comment: So after a while, I figured out the problem. You cannot use GetLindBindingData type on the service especially since it's not intended for backend dev. More accurately, it can't interpret the EF SQL statement as it's not meant to work with EF.